# Android Gallery application source code download (after hack)

Tags: android, gallery

> The kernel.org site which hosts the Android git repository has been
>   hacked

But I am trying to get Android Gallery application source code. Not to compile, just to read through it. Is there any link to an alternative location? May be someone cloned it on github, or something like this?

Comment: Read this article for complete source code - http://developine.com/develop-android-image-gallery-app-kotlin-with-source-code/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will https://github.com/android do the trick?

Edit: Cyanogen seems to have it, although it may be a patched version: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery

Comment: Unsuccessfully I see no Gallery.git here

Comment: alex2k8: Seems that Cyanogen has a (patched) mirror (see above).

Comment: The name is confusing, they called it android_packages_apps_Gallery, but what it really contains is the Camera.git

Comment: Well, thought this is a different .git, it seems to have some usefull info I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the official Google source:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/